# Fstab Mount new LVG

Tags: mount, fstab, lvm

I am having difficulty auto-mounting my newly created LVG. I tried adding the following line to /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/vgBackup/lvBackup /home/stuart/volume_backup ext3 defaults 0 1
```

I also tried swapping the /dev/vgBackup/lvBackup with something similar to `UUID=f7b9a5e3-4fa3-4bfd-b9af-bf126c296213`
based on the id that came up when I manually mounted the drive from nautilus by clicking on the volume (it showed up in /media).
Unfortunately, with both cases, I get a bootup message telling me that mounting fails and I have to press S to skip.

Manually mounting the drive from the CLI with:

```
sudo mount /dev/vgBackup/lvBackup /home/stuart/volume_backup
```

works though.

Perhaps fstab is the wrong tool to use? Ideally the drive should be available to write to for the stuart user instead of root.

**Additional Info**

- The drive currently uses the ext3 filesystem
- 3.5TB in size.
- consists of a 3TB and a 500G physical drives

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual way to mount LVM volumes seems to be via the device mapper symlink at /dev/mapper/*vgname-lvname*, for example if I have the following volumes

```
$ sudo lvs
  LV     VG   Attr   LSize  Origin Snap%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  root   t60p -wi-ao 89.92g                                      
  swap_1 t60p -wi-ao  3.00g
```

then

```
$ grep '/dev' /etc/fstab
/dev/mapper/t60p-root /                 ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/t60p-swap_1 none            swap    sw                0       0
```

This example comes from a 12.04 Server install with whole-disk LVM selected at install time, so the fstab is the one created by the installer. If I understand your naming convention correctly, the equivalent for your backup volume would be

```
/dev/mapper/vgBackup-lvBackup /home/stuart/volume_backup ext3 defaults 0 1
```

You should also be able to use the UUID corresponding to the mapper link, which you can get from blkid e.g. the output of `sudo blkid -c /dev/null`

You may also need to run `sudo update-initramfs -u` in order to make the device mappings available during boot.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me. When I ran sudo blkid -c /dev/null it clearly showed that it was actually set to ext4 but I swear that when I ran make2fs, I created an ext3 filesystem. Is it possible that I made ext4 partitions and an ext3 filesystem, a mistake that will bite me later?

Comment: @steeldriver It's not working 100% for me. Please refer to my question at http://askubuntu.com/questions/728174/using-lvm-in-the-already-running-ubuntu-system/730655. Please help if you can? Thanks in advance.