# Issue logging in ubuntu after update

Tags: unity

I am really hoping someone can help, been trying to fix this all morning
I turned my laptop on this morning, and I get the error "Your system is running in low-graphics mode", and nothing changes if i follow the steps.

If I press CTRL + ALT + F1; type "startx" the desktop loads fine. I can then open a terminal, run "unity", and the desktop works like it did before.

Any ideas? I have googled a lot and can't seem to find any fix. I have reinstalled my drivers so many times, and nothing fixes it. I think they must be fine though, as I can get on by following the steps above.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting screen like this?
[image]

as mentioned in my [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728174/using-lvm-in-the-already-running-ubuntu-system)

Your issue is unrelated to mine. **Just undo the last action you did to get back into last working good configuration.**

Comment: This is the exact screen I am getting. I did not make any changes, just did the updates via the update center. I may have messed with a few things to try and get it working when I first got the problem though.

It seems so strange that I can get in via startx. But the login screen won't appear!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I fixed it! I checked the logs in

/var/log/lightdm

The lightdm.log file showed an error with greeter. I checked the x-0-greeter.log file, and it said there was an error with /var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority.

I checked there, and the file didn't exist! I had the file in the home directory, so I copied that, to there, chowned and chmod it and it worked! Wooh! :)