# Newbie, want to install on 2 drives

Tags: system-installation

I have Windows 7 installed on an SSD, and my User-Data on a hard drive. I've got room, and a partition free on both. So can I install Ubuntu using my SSD for Boot/System/SWAP only, and use the hard drive for User Data? If so, how would I do this? Thanks

Comment: yes, put /home on the hard drive. Make sure you understand linux partitioning before installing

Comment: Similar questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/336439/any-problems-with-this-partition-scheme and:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/461394/how-to-partition-ssdhdd and:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Answer (score 0):

Yes very much. If you are not comfortable with disk partitioning and linux - I will suggest do all the partitioning operations in Windows 7-> Disk management. And then install linux. At the time of installing linux choose 'something else' as mentioned in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation).
Rest everything is almost the same after this step.

Make sure that Windows allows only 4 primary partitions. One can have extended partitions within primary partitions.

Within Linux one can make use of [Logical Volume manager](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-lvm.html) to create logical volumes which can span across drives and gives you a lot of flexibility. I have one detailed thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728174/using-lvm-in-the-already-running-ubuntu-system) where i am using /opt within LVM. That page has lot of other pointers which you can read for your reference.

A LVM(/dev/sdb3) looks like this in Linux's gparted tool
[image]

You can install gparted like this

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Comment: Do not create partitions with Windows, it may convert to dynamic partitions which are not Linux compatible. But do use Windows to resize any NTFS partitions and reboot immediately to let it run chkdsk.