# Installing Linux and Windows on SSD and HDD from scratch

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

There are quite a lot of questions like this but they are either unanswered or aren't enough to make me fully understand how to do this.

I just bought parts for a new computer, so I have a fresh and empty SSD (128 GB) and HDD (1 TB). My plan is to install both Linux and Windows on the SSD as well as some games from Windows, and the rest of the data in the HDD.

From my understading, the process is:

1. Install Windows on SSD
2. Move the content of the User folder to the HDD
3. Make a partition in both the SSD and HDD for Linux
4. Install Linux in SSD with `/home` (and maybe `/var`) in HDD

And my questions are:

- Is that process correct?
- In order to put `/home` in the HDD, should I do it during the installation, or later with symbolic links?
- Are `/var` or `/tmp` worth moving away from the SSD?
- Windows programs usually install in a `Program Files` folder outside of the User folder. When installing a program, will I have to change directory to the HDD every time, or am I suposed to move the `Program Files` folder in the same way I move the contents of User?
- 40 GB seems to be enough for the Linux SSD partition. Is that right?
- Can I place the `swap` partition in the HDD even if `/` is in the SSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is right.

> "In order to put /home in the HDD, should I do it during the
>   installation, or later with symbolic links?"

At the time of install - choose something else for custom partitioning. It's not symbolic link but /home will be in it's own partition.

> "Are /var or /tmp worth moving away from the SSD?"

Depends on your current and future needs but it's okay to do so.

> "Windows programs usually install in a Program Files folder outside of
>   the User folder. When installing a program, will I have to change
>   directory to the HDD every time, or am I supposed to move the Program
>   Files folder in the same way I move the contents of User?"

In Linux most of the programs are installed under /usr so you can create a separate partition for /usr also. A lot of folks install apps and programs under /opt. It's also a good candidate for it's own partition.

"40 GB seems to be enough for the Linux SSD partition. Is that right?"

> It's perfectly fine. Entire Linux can be installed in just 10 GB if
>   you want.

"Can I place the swap partition in the HDD even if / is in the SSD?"
Yes you can. Swap is not used to a great extent unless you put your computer under hibernation or you are low on memory.

***Note : I will advise you to use gparted for partitioning and LVM for logical volumes as they give you a lot of flexibility. You can refer to my earlier question about LVM at [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728174/using-lvm-in-the-already-running-ubuntu-system). It has a lot of pointers/references for other resources.***

Comment: So you recommend doing the partitions and logical volumes (i'm reading about what those are) from the Ubuntu live CD?

Comment: @Jurcan Yes. Using LVM you can make your partitions span across drives and it gives you a lot flexibility as not everybody is fully aware how much space is needed for all the partitions at the time of install.