# Put Ubuntu and Windows games on SSD?

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, partitioning, ssd, windows-10

Oh boy, another Windows/Ubuntu SSD/HDD question.

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but I've looked everywhere and can't figure out how to do this. Basically, I'm going to have Windows on a 1TB HDD. I'm also going to install Ubuntu to a second (solid state) drive on the same laptop. I want to partition some space out so I can put some Windows games and applications on the SSD along with linux.

How do I partition it this way? Do I do it while installing Linux through the "something else" checkmark? Also, do I format the space to be used by Windows as FAT?

Would I even benefit from moving Windows apps to the SSD when the Windows OS itself is on the HDD?

Comment: Put both the OS's on the SSD and your games on the HDD. The SSD does not come into play when games are in memory and read from memory.

Comment: @Rinzwind Ah, okay. So I don't put my games on the ssd and instead  basically follow the instructions from here?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/742233/installing-linux-and-windows-on-ssd-and-hdd-from-scratch
Turns out this is a duplicate after all, I guess.